# How do I control TeamViewer in a Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, teamviewer

I have TeamViewer installed (through the official GUI installer) under OS X on a PC. I'd like to find out the ID of said computer through SSH, which should be printed to terminal when I start TeamViewer, but I can't seem to be able to launch it since it already is running. Killing the process will not solve it as it's auto-regenerating. As a matter of fact, even `sudo launchctl stop com.teamviewer.service` doesn't seem to do anything.

Now, apparently, teamviewer should be able to stop itself if I were to run [`teamviewer --daemon stop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16323024/568855), but I can't get any arguments to work:

```
Undercompy-Mac:MacOS underyx$ ./TeamViewer --daemon stop
A TeamViewer instance is already running.
Undercompy-Mac:MacOS underyx$ ./TeamViewer --help
A TeamViewer instance is already running.
Undercompy-Mac:MacOS underyx$ ./TeamViewer
A TeamViewer instance is already running.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.teamviewer.teamviewer9.plist ClientID
```

This Terminal command will read the Client ID from the application's preferences file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this tomorrow and accept your answer if it really does work.

Comment: No problem bro, just remember to sub the 9 for whatever version youre running, myself, Im trying to automate the TeamViewer 9 Host install for a Mac 10.9..

Comment: Gotcha. Quick sidenote: I had to flag your other answer as it's actually a completely different question inatead of an answer to this one. You might want to post that as a separate question, it'll gain a lot more visibility.

Comment: Could you expand your answer? As is, it's hard to tell exactly what that does.

Comment: I just edited it; c'mon I thought this was SuperUser!?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the type of solution you are looking for, but a solution neverthless.

The teamviewer.com site gives you the ability to store your Computers (via IDs).

So you add the computer once on teamviewers page, and you will be able to get the ID from there later on.

The ID doesnt change as far as I know, so there should not be a need to ssh into the box to retrieve it each time.